# How is the complex differential form $d\overline{z}$ defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Consider a two-dimensional real smooth manifold $M$. For simplicity, take $M=\mathbb{R}^2$. We can talk about the $1$-forms, $dx$ and $dy$; the $2$-form $dx\wedge dy$, where $x$ and $y$ are the coordinate maps. Fix a point $p\in M$. The differential $(dx)_p$ is an element of the dual of the (real) tangent space $T_pM$.

For a one-dimensional complex analytic manifold $N$, say $\mathbb{C}$, we can talk about the complex $1$-forms, $dz$, $d\overline{z}$. (I know nothing but the names of these two objects in the complex case.) Naively, $(dz)_q$ is an element in the dual of the "(complex) tangent space" $T_qN$ where $z$ is the coordinate map. But there is only one complex dimension. How is $d\overline{z}$ really defined?

Comment: There are different interpretations in different circumstances. Are we talking about tensors on the holomorphic tangent space or on the complexified tangent space? See, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634508/computing-with-differential-forms-on-the-tangent-space-of-a-complex-manifold/3635589#3635589) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885191/definition-of-dz-i-otimes-d-barz-j-frac-partial-partial-z-m-c-frac-part/2885936#2885936).

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks a lot for the links! I know almost zero in complex geometry other than the definition of a complex manifold. I have just seen the 1-forms $dz$ and $d\overline{z}$ in many places and naively thought that there should be some analog of "(complex) tangent space" for the complex manifold. If you don't mind: what's the difference between "[holomophic tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_tangent_bundle#Definition)" and the "complexified tangent space"? I may mistakenly think that they are the same.

Comment: If you have a complex $n$-manifold, the holomorphic tangent space (as you can figure out from reading my answers at those links) is the $n$-dimensional complex vector space spanned by $\partial/\partial z^1,\dots,\partial/\partial z^n$ (so the usual notion of tangent space, working with a holomorphic chart). However, you can look at the tangent space as a *real* manifold and then complexify; this will have complex dimension $2n$ and contains (naturally) the holomorphic subspace and its complex conjugate ("anti-holomorphic"). The latter is spanned by the $\partial/\partial\bar z^j$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks for the elaboration!

Answer (score 2):

For $M=\mathbb{C}=\{x+\sqrt{-1}y:x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$, 
$dz=dx+\sqrt{-1}dy$ and $d\overline{z}$ is the conjugate of $dz$, i.e. 
$$d\overline{z}=dx-\sqrt{-1}dy.$$

To think about this, remember that for $M=\mathbb{R}^2$, $1$-forms $dx$ and $dy$ are dual to $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in the sense that 
$$dx(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=dy(\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=1\mbox{ and }
dx(\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=dy(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=0.$$

With these in mind, $dz$ and $d\overline{z}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ are dual to 
$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$ in the sense that 
$$dz(\frac{\partial}{\partial z})=d\overline{z}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}})=1\mbox{ and }
dz(\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}})=d\overline{z}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z})=0.$$
For example, to check $\displaystyle dz(\frac{\partial}{\partial z})=1$, we compute
$$dz(\frac{\partial}{\partial z})=(dx+\sqrt{-1}dy)\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\right)\\
=\frac{1}{2}\left[dx\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)
+\sqrt{-1}dy\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)
-\sqrt{-1}dx\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
+dy\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\right]
=1.$$
The other can be checked similarly.